# How do I use Joomla article variables inside modules?

Tags: php, variables, module, joomla3.0

For getting the article alias of the current/active article, I can use

```
<?php echo $article->alias;?>
```

This will work fine if I put that code inside the article itself.
However when I put this code inside a Joomla module, it echos nothing;
Not even when I insert the module inside the article itself (with Modules Anywhere from Regular Labs).

How can I make use of the Joomla variables (or this one in particular) within a module?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have found an alternate solution that seems to give me the desired result.

```
<?php $alias=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>

<?php echo $alias;?>
```

This apparently returns the last part of an URL string (everything behind the last slash).